# Recursion in Assembly x86: Fibonacci

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, fibonacci

I am trying to code a recursive fibonacci sequence in assembly, but it is not working for some reason.

It does not give an error, but the output number is always wrong.

```
section .bss
  _bss_start:
    ; store max iterations
    max_iterations resb 4
  _bss_end:

section .text
  global _start

; initialise the function variables
_start:
  mov dword [max_iterations], 11
  mov edx, 0
  push 0
  push 1
  jmp fib

fib:
  ; clear registers
  mov eax, 0
  mov ebx, 0
  mov ecx, 0
  ; handle fibonacci math
  pop ebx
  pop eax
  add ecx, eax
  add ecx, ebx
  push eax
  push ebx
  push ecx
  ; incriment counter / exit contitions
  inc edx
  cmp edx, [max_iterations]
  je print
  ; recursive step
  call fib
  ret

print:
  mov eax, 1
  pop ebx
  int 0x80
```

For instance, the above code prints a value of 79 rather than 144 (11th fibonacci number).

Alternatively, if I make

```
mov dword [max_iterations], 4
```

Then the above code prints 178 rather than 5 (5th fibonacci number).

Any one have an idea?

K

Comment: Wrong how?  Like always 0?  Is it right for small numbers that fit in the 1-byte exit status of a Linux process, and truncated for larger ones?  (mod 256)  An [mcve] needs details like that so people know what kind of bug they're looking for.

Comment: right sorry, will update that

Comment: You've declared `max_iterations` as a single byte of storage, yet use it like has 4 bytes.

Comment: You declare `max_iterations` as 1 byte then treat it like a DWORD: `mov dword [max_iterations], 11`

Comment: oh yeah, will update that

Comment: 144 is the 12th Fibonacci number, not 11th.  Fib(5) is 5, though, so you are counting from the same starting point as normal for that one.  Anyway, use a debugger so you can see register values, not just the single exit-status number (low byte of one value from the very end of your loop.)

Comment: The first thing your `fib` function does is pop things from the stack, which means it will remove the return address. You're not supposed to pop function arguments, just read them from memory normally (or use registers).

Comment: Good catch, thanks

Answer (score 2):

As an approach, you should try to debug it with the smallest possible input, like 1 iteration.  That will be most revealing as you can watch it do the wrong thing in great detail without worrying about multiple recursing's.  When that works, go to 2 iterations.

When you use complex addressing modes, it is harder to debug as we cannot see what the processor is doing.  So, when an instruction using a complex addressing mode doesn't work, and you want to debug it, then split that instruction into 2 instructions as follows:

```
mov   dword [fibonacci_seq + edx + 4], ecx
---
lea   esi, [fibonacci_seq + edx + 4]
mov   [esi], ecx
```

With the alternate code sequence, you can observe the value of the addressing mode computation, which will provide you with additional debugging insight.

As another example:

```
cmp edx, [max_iterations]
---
mov edi, [max_iterations]
cmp edx, edi
```

Using the 2 instruction version, you will be able to see what value the processor is comparing `edx` with.

Or better, do that that `mov` load once before the loop, so you're keeping the loop bound in a register all the time.  That's what you should normally do when you have enough registers, only using memory when you run out.

---

You are `jmp`ing to `fib` from one place in the code and `call`ing it from another.  Though your logic should work because when you've reached the limit, you don't return to the main, ***this is really bad form***: to mix main code with function.  More on that below...

---

```
mov dword [fibonacci_seq + edx + 4], ecx
```

Is this working for you?  You're only incrementing `edx` by 1.  Perhaps you wanted:

```
mov dword [fibonacci_seq + edx * 4], ecx
```

---

I would argue that your code is not really recursive.

```
call fib      ; jumps to fib, pushes a return address
ret           ; never, ever reached, so, pointless
---
jmp fib       ; iterate w/o pushing unwanted return address onto the stack
```

The 1-instruction `jmp` will be superior to the `call` as a mechanism to iterate, in part b/c it doesn't push an unnecessary return address onto the stack.

When you debug with 2 iterations, you'll probably see that the unused return address pushed by the call messes up your "parameter" passing, pops.

To expand on the "recursion", when the iteration stops and control transfers to `print`, there will be some 11 (depending on iteration count) unused return addresses on the stack (modulo the interference by the pop's and pushes).

The recursive call is only used for iteration, the recursion never unwinds.  Thus, I would argue it's not recursive (not even tail recursive) — it just erroneously pushes some unused return addresses onto the stack — that's not recursion.

Comment: Good point, I have edited the code to try and make the problem more clear

Answer (score 0):

This line is your main problem:

```
mov dword [fibonacci_seq + edx + 4], ecx
```

Because of the +4, you never write to the first entry of the "array". And because you only increment EDX by 1,  each write to the array overwrites 3 bytes of the previous entry. Try this instead:

```
    mov dword [fibonacci_seq + edx * 4], ecx
```

Comment: right, I will remove that and update the description with findings

Answer (score -1):

A bit of redesign, as I did not realise that the call instruction used the stack in this way, and the solution is here

```
section .bss
  _bss_start:
    ; store max iterations and current iteration
    max_iterations resb 4
    iteration resb 4
    ; store arguments
    n_0 resb 4
    n_1 resb 4
  _bss_end:

section .text
  global _start

; initialise the function variables
_start:
  mov dword [max_iterations], 11
  mov dword [iteration], 0
  mov dword [n_0], 0
  mov dword [n_1], 1
  jmp fib

fib:
  mov ecx, 0
  mov edx, 0
  mov eax, [n_0]
  mov ebx, [n_1]
  add ecx, eax
  add ecx, ebx
  mov edx, [n_1]
  mov dword [n_0], edx
  mov dword [n_1], ecx

  mov edx, [iteration]
  inc edx
  mov dword [iteration], edx

  cmp edx, [max_iterations]
  je print

  call fib
  ret

print:
  mov eax, 1
  mov ebx, [n_1]
  int 0x80
```

Comment: While that fixes the interference between the call instruction and the pop/push parameter  passing, this is still not recursive.  The `call` transfers control to (top of) `fib`  unconditionally, and the `ret` will never ever be executed.  When it goes to `print` there will be unused return addresses on the stack, whenever there's more than 1 iteration.  Might as well `jmp` to fib instead of using `call`.